# Setting "DD/MM/YYYY" format in MUI

Tags: reactjs, date, datepicker, material-ui

In my MUI form I'm using `DatePicker` to select dates for departure and return of users. But when I used `.toLocaleDateString()` it set my dates in `mm-dd-yyyy` format. But I wanted to set them as `dd-mm-yyyy` format. For that I've passed `'en-GB'` as parameter in `.toLocaleDateString()`. But in the DatePicker `TextField` it shows a red border [Like this](https://ibb.co/x2k3Tp4) and the pre-defined date (from the state) are also gone. Without the parameter it shows [This](https://ibb.co/FmNVt0h) which is the `mm-dd-yyyy` format. From the similar previous questions I even tried it through `moment` package and set the `dt` variable as `moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY")` but it is still showing red border around the text field. I know this question was asked a lot of times before and I went through all of them and got no solution.

**Date picker**

```
const dt = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  console.log(dt);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    from: "",
    to: "",
    depart: dt,
    return: dt,
    noOfPassenger: 1,
    tripType: "Return",
  });

   {/* App component  */}
       <div className="dates">
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DatePicker
              label="Departure Date"
              disablePast
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormData({
                  ...formData,
                  depart: e.toLocaleDateString(),
                })
              }
              value={formData.depart}
              renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} required />}
            />
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `TextField` like here: https://codesandbox.io/s/p268w?file=/demo.js
or `DesktopDatePicker` like here: https://codesandbox.io/s/uuonn?file=/demo.js

Comment: @HlebShypula I did use `inputFormat` in the datepicker but it didn't work..later I solved this by adding `date-fns` package and the set the input format in the datepicker

Answer (score 8):

In my case I used a DateRangePicker, but it's the same across all pickers.
Just set the inputFormat like here:

```
<DateRangePicker
     startText={t`From`}
     endText={t`To`}
     value={dateValue}
     inputFormat="dd.MM.yyyy"
     onChange={(newValue) => {
         setDateValue(newValue);
         console.log(newValue);
     }}
     renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
        <React.Fragment>
            <TextField {...startProps} />
            <TextField {...endProps} />
        </React.Fragment>
     )}
/>
```

Comment: use `format` instead of `inputFormat` for MUI version 6.x+

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by importing this package `import 'dayjs/locale/en-gb';`

Here is an example:

```
'use client'; //  skip this if you're not using NextJs

import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import 'dayjs/locale/en-gb';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export default function MuiLocalizationProvider({ children }: Props) {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="en-gb">
      {children}
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

After adding the provider, you can now use the date picker like this

```
const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState<Dayjs | null>(null);
<DatePicker
  label="Due Date"
  value={dueDate}
  onChange={(newDueDate) => setDueDate(newDueDate)}
/>
```

For more details https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/adapters-locale/

Answer (score 1):

Emanuel Avram has already given a good answer. I will just add.
The value (date) of the component must have the same format defined internally, so it's no use using "toLocaleString()" without changing the internal format. Use the "inputFormat" property.

```js
// "dd" = "Su", "Mo", ..., "Sa"
// "DD" = "01", "02", ..., "31"
inputFormat="dd/MM/YYYY" // Tu/09/2022
inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" // 09/13/2022
```

```
<DatePicker
    label="Departure Date"
    inputFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" // 13-09-2022
    onChange={(e) =>
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            depart: e.toLocaleDateString(),
        })
    }
    value={formData.depart}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} required />}
/>
```